# Use uniform convergence to control the derivative of function

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, geometric-measure-theory

Let $f_n$: $I:=[-1,1]\to \mathbb R$ be given, and we also assume that $f_n\in C^\infty(I)$.

Assume $f_n\to 0$ uniformly in $I$, and we know
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}\int_I\sqrt{1+(f'_n)^2}<\infty
$$
i.e., the length of the graph of $f_n$ is bounded.

My question: can we deduce that 
$$
\limsup_{n\to \infty}\,\left(\sup_{x\in I'}|f_n'(x)|\right)<\infty
$$
for some subinterval $I'\subset I$? How large $I'$ could be? i.e., can we prove that $\mathcal L^1(I\setminus I')=0$?

How about $f_n''$?

Comment: Does your function has any property? I.e. is piecewise linear? In that case it is true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the derivatives need not bounded on any subinterval.  Consider 
$$
f_n(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} (\cos  \sqrt{n}x  )^n
$$
The length of the graph is uniformly bounded, since there are about $\sqrt{n}$ waves of height $1/\sqrt{n}$.

On the other hand, $$\sup \left| \frac{d}{dx} (\cos x)^n \right|\to \infty$$ (this is clear from the shape of the graph: when $n$ is large, there is a narrow peak of height $1$). The scaling by $\sqrt{n}$ does not change the supremum of derivative, but makes it attained more often. As a result, $f_n'$ becomes increasingly large increasingly often.